# j2me audio player

Tags: java-me, media-player, mmapi

I created a audio player using following code.

```
try {

    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("bell.wav");

    player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/X-wav");

    player.realize();

    player.prefetch();
    player.start();


}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();

}
catch (MediaException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

This code works on the simulator without any problem. But it is not working in the phone.
MediaException is thrown. I think phone does not support for this player. 
Have there any solutions for this ?

Comment: did you try `createPlayer(is, "audio/wav")` or `createPlayer(is, "wav")`? Also when on the phone you could display [Alert](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Alert.html) with the text of `ex.getMessage()` from within MediaException catch block to find more details - did you consider that?

Comment: yes I displayed a message under the mediaexception so that message is displayed on the phone but audio is started in the simulator without any problem.

Comment: what was the message on the phone? Also, does your phone support MIDP 2 (JSR 118)? I ask because per my recollection `wav` format is required to be supported by MIDP 2

Comment: Message is not added for this code. I appended a message to form when error checking. Phone supports for MIDP2. I tried createPlayer(is, "audio/X-wav") it works on the simulator but createPlayer(is, "wav") does nit work, which gives a mediaException in simulator also.

Comment: what about `"audio/wav"`? - did you try it?

Comment: you mean, `"audio/wav"` is working both in emulator and in the real prhone, right?

Comment: No it is working in only simulator.

Comment: interesting. Did you try to see the output of [Manager.getSupportedContentTypes](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#getSupportedContentTypes(java.lang.String)) at the device? also, what is the size of your wav file?

Comment: No I didn't try that. My wav file size is 528KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to check what mime types are supported by the device by checking

```
Manager.getSupportedContentTypes(String protocol);
```

and

```
Manager.getSupportedProtocols(String content_type);
```

You can also try using an URL instead of InputStream

```
Manager.createPlayer(String url);
```